# ProvidedIn: 'any' in Angular 14+ is deprecated. What would be a good replacement?

Tags: angular

According to [Angular Official Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#providedIn:%7E:text=%27any%27%20%3A%20Provides%20a%20unique%20instance%20in%20each%20lazy%20loaded%20module%20while%20all%20eagerly%20loaded%20modules%20share%20one%20instance.%20This%20option%20is%20DEPRECATED.) for Angular 14+, `any` is depreciated:

> any' : Provides a unique instance in each lazy loaded module while all eagerly loaded modules share one instance. This option is DEPRECATED.

I haven't found anything on the web. What would be a good replacement for it?

Comment: According to the [page listing deprecated features](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularcore), there is no replacement for that option. There's also the [blog post announcing the change](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v15-is-now-available-df7be7f2f4c8) under the Deprecations section.

Comment: Probably not applicable to Angular, but look up `unknown`

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine You seem to misunderstood my question. It's not about `any` type in TypeScript.

Comment: Sure. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using root instead of `any` or `NgModule`. Those two have next to no use cases and are most likely used incorrectly. You can read further here: [Angular - Update Angular to v15](https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-15#v15-dp-05)

### Update

Instead of using the `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'any' })`, you should now be using `@Injectable({ providedIn: null })`.

This will allow you to create a new instance every time you import the service in `@NgModule({ })`, `@Component({ })` or/and `@Directive({ })`.

##### Here's an example of implementation:

###### Service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: null })
export class MyService { }
```

###### Module:

```
@NgModule({ providers: [ MyService ] })
export class MyModule { }
```

##### Sources:

- [Angular provideIn deprecation](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/47616#issue-1395276105)
- [Angular Injectable Decorator Documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable#options)

Comment: I use `ProvidedIn: any` to provide a unique instance in each lazy loaded module. I don't want to share that injectable with other module. I guess in my case, I should use [NgModule.providers](https://angular.io/api/core/NgModule#providers).

Comment: In that case the only alternative seems to be this: `@NgModule({ providers: [Service] })`. It seems to not be tree-shackable thought. For more info , see: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/47616#:~:text=NgModule%2C%20use%20NgModule.providers%20instead.
and
https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules

Comment: This is still not a very satisfying answer to the question. If I want a separate instance of a given service in every module that imports it, then should I include this `providers` line in every module? And then I suppose the service should be set up with `providedIn: null`? Or how exactly should I configure this?

Comment: I've not tested it, but according to the doc, you assessment seems right. In your service, you should have `@Injectable({ providedIn: null })` and you can then use `@NgModule({ providers: [ MyService ] })`. You can also use it with `@Component({ })` and `@Directive({ })`.