# Angular Tests. ProvidedIn: Module breaking

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-unit-test

Currently I am using a service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: MyModule
})
export class MyService {
 //... do stuff
}

---

@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyComp],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    ComponentsModule,
    MyCompRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [MyService]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

I have been hours trying to understand why I am getting a error:

> MyComponent should exist FAILED TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵcmp')

This only happens on Karma Jasmine unit tests. The code itself works marvellously!

Unfortunately I cannot use `providedIn: 'root'` but if I do use it though, I do not get the error. Same with the `providedIn: 'any'`

```js
describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let service: MyService;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        ComponentsModule,
        SharedModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        MyService,
        HttpService
      ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: providedIn module is deprecated. Why can't use you `providedIn: 'root'` ?

Comment: I literally facepalmed when I saw your comment! I had completely forgot about that change! the documentation is out of date. This fixed it! Please add an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing in an `NgModule` is deprecated.

`providedIn: 'root'` is the way to go  !

Comment: Just to clarify. The method used on the question works. It's on unit testing that it creates problems. as @Mathieu said the usage of `providedIn: <ModuleName>` is technically deprecated and te `providedIn: null` should be used.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74492612/providedin-any-in-angular-14-is-deprecated-what-would-be-a-good-replacement

But testing is a pain in Angular, sometimes you have to choose good code / code coverage.